# Hilt injection into activity before super.onCreate()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I defined my own **LayoutInflater.Factory2** class in a separate module. I want to inject it into each activity in my App, but the point is that I have to set this factory before activity's **super.onCreate()** method.
When I using Hilt it makes an injection right after super.onCreate(). So I have an UninitializedPropertyAccessException.

Is there any opportunity to have an injection before super.onCreate with Hilt?

Below is my example of module's di.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DynamicThemeModule {
    @FlowPreview
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDynamicThemeConfigurator(
        repository: AttrRepository
    ): DynamicTheme<AttrInfo> {
        return DynamicThemeConfigurator(repository)
    }
}
```

Comment: You answered your own question. Hilt injects after supe.onCreate(), so you can't inject something before it

Comment: Well, I guess di is inappropriate here. So the only solution is to manually instantiate Factory2 implementation in App class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject the class before onCreate by using [Entry Points](https://dagger.dev/hilt/entry-points) like this.

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
   
   @EntryPoint
   @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
   interface DynamicThemeFactory {
      fun getDynamicTheme() : DynamicTheme<AttrInfo>
   }

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      val factory = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(this, DynamicThemeFactory::class.java)
      val dynamicTheme = factory.getDynamicTheme()
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   }
}
```

If you need something like this a lot Id recommend creating an instance of it in the companion object of your Application class when your application starts (`onCreate`). That is before any of your views are created. So you don´t need to jump threw those hoops all the time, but can just access the instance that already exists. This code above won´t be available in `attachBaseContext`, when you need it there you have to create it in your application class I think.